# Notice: Array to String Conversion Magento 2.1.14

Tags: magento2

```
<select id="report_sitioweb" name="sitioweb" title="Sitio Web" class=" required-entry _required select multiselect admin__control-multiselect" data-ui-id="uploadattributes-attributes-edit-form-fieldset-element-select-sitioweb" multiple="multiple" aria-required="true"> 
        <?php 
            $stores = $this->getStoreData();
            foreach ($stores as $key => $value) {
                echo '<option value="',$key,'">',$value,'</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
```

Help me! please!

Comment: There should be some value which is not a string but it is an array. Instead of echo, use var_dump and check.

Comment: use like echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'".$value."'</option>';

Comment: Var_dump throws me this: "
array(2) {
  ["label"]=&gt;
  string(16) "Store 1"
  ["value"]=&gt;
  int(2)
}
string(9) "

Comment: Is it the the output of var_dump($value)?

Comment: yes thats what throws

Comment: try this  `echo '<option value="'.$value['value'].'">'.$value['label'].'</option>';`

Comment: Welcome! happy to help you,  have a happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

You can return stores object as Data like this.

```
public function getStoreData() {
 return $this->_storeManager->getStores();
}
```

And use foreach in template file like this:

```
$stores = $this->getStoreData();
 foreach ($stores as $key => $value) {
   echo '<option value="'.$value->getId().'">'.$value->getName().'</option>';
 }
```

OR

as per your code, you need to do this:

```
<?php
$stores = $this->getStoreData();
foreach ($stores as $value) {
 echo '<option value="'.$value['value'].'">'.$value['label'].'</option>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

replace your code like this.

```
<select id="report_sitioweb" name="sitioweb" title="Sitio Web" class=" required-entry _required select multiselect admin__control-multiselect" data-ui-id="uploadattributes-attributes-edit-form-fieldset-element-select-sitioweb" multiple="multiple" aria-required="true"> 
        <?php 
            $stores = $this->getStoreData();
            foreach ($stores as $store) {
        echo "<option value=".$store['value'].">".$store['label']."</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
```

Comment: This does not work :(

Comment: Can you tell me $stores = $this->getStoreData(); what you try to do here?
Do you want show store name into dropdown as label and it code as value?

Comment: I want the drop-down menu to show all the stores that array brings

Comment: can you share the code of $this->getStoreData() this function?

Comment: public function getStoreData()
    {
        $storeManagerDataList = $this->_storeManager->getStores();
         $options = array();
         
         foreach ($storeManagerDataList as $key => $value) {
                   $options[] = ['label' => $value['name'], 'value' => $key];
         }
         return $options;
    }

Comment: $this->_storeManager is instance of this class Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface right?

Comment: I edit my answer, Kindly check.

Comment: If answer help you, accept it, So it help other in community as well.